# Symbol documentation and implementation code in haskell-mode

Tags: haskell-mode

I'm learning Haskell. One of first steps was to make pleasant development environment. I've already found `haskell-mode`, `intero` and some more useful packages but I miss offline/online documentation for the symbol at point.

What I've already found looks alike what I need is [this](http://haskell.github.io/haskell-mode/manual/latest/Browsing-Haddocks.html#Browsing-Haddocks) but have no success with configuration. I have `cabal` installed from `haskell-platform` on `ubuntu 14.04` but don't have `~/.cabal/share/doc/`. What I expect is when the cursor is on e.g. `repeat` function and `C-c C-d` is presed it shows the some documentation for the function. It's nice to have some basic information about function signature in mini buffer but for a newcomer it would be great to have access to full documentation.

What is prefered way to get symbols full documentation inside Emacs?

Comment: I'm also a haskell beginner and DO NOT use `haskell-platform`. Instead, configure haskell to use `haskell-stack`. Get rid of all traces of `haskell-platform`. `intero` is made to work with stack. And, I had created an issue very similar to this in interos github page and apparently, they will add haddock support to intero in the future.

ATM, the best way to get documentation inside of emacs might be [`helm-dash`](https://github.com/areina/helm-dash).

Comment: It is same as Hoogle support already contained in `haskell-mode`. Btw, it is good enouth to me. Also, `intero` support for documentation would be much more pleasant. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/) is what I serching for. At this moment there is (at least) two ways to integrate it nicely with Emacs.

- Directly through `haskell-mode`. Fuction which should be called with cursor on desired symbol is `haskell-hoogle-lookup-from-local`. It will ask you to run `hoogle` local server for the first time.
  You also have to install `hoogle` in your `stack` sandbox via:

  > stack install hoogle

  and you have to generate `hoogle` local documentation with:

  > hoogle generate
- Using [`helm-dash`](https://github.com/areina/helm-dash) which supports many other languages and envirnoments. Function which should be called when the cursor is on desired symbol is called `helm-dash-at-point`. You should also install Haskell docset with `M-x helm-dash-install-docset RET Haskell RET` and activate Haskell docset with `M-x helm-dash-activate-docset RET Haskell RET` (there is also a way to activate corresponding docset acording to active mode/language described [here](https://github.com/areina/helm-dash#buffer-local-docsets)).

Comment: Also `helm-hoogle`: https://melpa.org/#/helm-hoogle  Works great